# Float increment give wrong result

Tags: c#, unity, unityscript

I found something weird with my unity code :

```
public class heroesscript : MonoBehaviour {

    float counter = 0;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        counter += 0.02f;
        print (counter);
    }
}
```

When I'm executing this code, I get this in my console :

- 0.2
- 0.4
- 0.6
- 0.8
- 0.9999999

Anybody can explain this? How to avoid this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c151dt3s.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a [floating point precision error](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) and the reason why you shouldn't use `float` whenever you really care about precision (and try to avoid using direct comparison with them). Use `double` instead (but it has limited precision as well!).